Maven test pass, but with install tests fail
I'm using maven, liquibase in project and spock with groovy to test java code.
Normally my tests pass, but when I'm using packaging/install then tests fails with error of spring context initializing due to liquibase.
Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:/db/changelog.xml' was not found.
The path is ok and works in application, during maven test goal, but fail when I start install goal.
Do you have any idea where is any difference and problem? I have been already exhausted totally. :/

The full pom file or a reference to a project would be helpful... also which JDK versions, Maven Versions etc. you are using..
